# How to find APIs for different Oracle APPS module?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apps

I am just a beginner in Oracle APPS Technical.And i am facing difficulty for identify the appropriate api for a particular requirement Lets say create a sales order.I googled it and i found a package called "oe_order_pub" that are used for creating sales order.So my question is how to identify appropriate package among multiple package?

Answer (score 0):

The best place for you to go to is the Electronic Technical Reference Manuals (eTRM) located at [etrm.oracle.com](http://etrm.oracle.com/pls/etrm/etrm_search.search).  This site outlines all the objects (packages, tables, views, etc.) that are available for Oracle Apps and how to use.

I'd also suggest the [Oracle Developer Community](http://community.oracle.com) which has a lot of Apps-specific problems and resolutions.

To access either site, you'll need an Oracle account (you'll definitely need this if you plan on being an Apps developer).